# Inductive Crankshaft Sensor Operation

Tags: sensor, waveform, inductive

I would like any possible explanations/diagrams of how the waveform voltage rises at the point where the missing tooth/teeth of the reluctor wheel approach and pass the Inductive Sensor.
This is just to take the intrigue out of the Waveforms and the barebones explanation of Picoscope.

https://www.picoauto.com/library/automotive-guided-tests/crankshaft-inductive-floating-cranking/

In particular I am foxed by the last sentence of the 5th paragraph of the Further Guidance section in the above link.

"The missing tooth on the pulse wheel provides the main timing reference mark. As the gap passes through the magnetic field, there is a period of reduced disturbance and voltage. Furthermore, the trailing and leading edge of the teeth that immediately precede and follow the gap are further apart, thus they produce a larger net magnetic field disturbance and induced voltage."

[image: Waveform]

Thank You for any enlightenment !

Comment: Andy's answer is about as good as a clear, succinct, and correct answer gets. If you need more information, let him know by asking. He may be willing to expand on his comments for you. (Otherwise, if you do follow his comment well and it's all you needm then feel free to select it once you feel other, better answers won't arrive.)

Answer (score 1):

Because an inductive sensor is affected by all localized ferrous material in the vicinity of the probe face, when there **isn't** a missing tooth the relative peak-to-peak change in permeability as the teeth are passing is actually less then when there **is** a missing tooth passing by.

The missing tooth inevitably generates a higher p-p voltage signal because the p-p permeability change is higher.